# Returning from Space: Re-entry - from which book is this chapter taken?

Tags: reference-request

When googling about space travel, I stumbled upon this text: https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/cami/library/online_libraries/aerospace_medicine/tutorial/media/III.4.1.7_Returning_from_Space.pdf

Obviously, it looks like a chapter from a book, but I havn't been able to identify the book, or find any other chapters from it.

Does anyone recognise the book?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply traveling the URL "upwards" you get this: https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/cami/library/online_libraries/aerospace_medicine/tutorial/

It's an "online book", *Advanced Aerospace Medicine On-line*:

> This on-line aerospace medicine reference was designed to provide a comprehensive information source for use by Aviation Medical Examiners, Medical Officers of the Office of Aerospace Medicine, and anyone else interested in the subject matter. The text provides a basic understanding of the interaction between the human body and the aerospace environment. Some sections are intuitively simple, while others are somewhat complex. This diversity of level is intentional and reflects the wide range of concepts and issues associated with aviation and space travel.

Comment: oic, here are all of the parts of chapter 4, right here in "Section III" ;-0 https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/cami/library/online_libraries/aerospace_medicine/tutorial/section3/spacecraft_design/ I tried to do that and failed, you have the "magic touch" it seems.

Comment: Oh, now I feel stupid! I "travelled upwards" one step and got permission denied and stopped there.